# UIImageView .scaleAspectFit and autolayout not working programmatically from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I have several partly transparent PNG overlays to display overlaying one another in a view. The number of overlays varies depending on runtime conditions. I want to create the `UIImageView` instances in Swift and add them to the view.

I don't have any trouble getting the behaviour I want when adding an `UIImageView` in the storyboard and setting its image via Swift. In such a case, I pin the leading, trailing, top, and bottom of the `UIImageView` to the leading, trailing, top, and bottom of the parent wrapper `UIView`. In the attribute inspector for the `UIImageView`, I set "Content Mode" to "Aspect Fit" and the large image is scaled down nicely when Swift sets the image. The user can see the whole image on the little iPhone screen.

When I dynamically create a `UIImageView` and add it to the same parent wrapper `UIView`, I'm having a problem with constraints. There are too many constraints to satisfy.

I cannot figure out why the `UIImageView` created via Swift is different from the `UIImageView` created via the storyboard.

How can I get the `UIImageView` created via Swift to behave just like the `UIImageView` created via the storyboard?

The Swift code that sets the image on the `UIImageView` created via the storyboard and the `UIImageView` created via Swift.

```
override func viewDidLoad() -> Void {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    let imageFilePath: String = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("img/a.png", isDirectory: false).path;

    // Use the outlet to set the image in the UIImageView created in the storyboard.
    // This works.

    self.storyboardImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFilePath);

    // Create a UIImageView programatically and add it to the same wrapper UIView
    // that also contains the UIImageView above.
    // This doesn't work.

    let swiftImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFilePath));

    // The presence of the following line makes no difference
    //
    swiftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill;

    self.storyboardWrapperView.addSubview(swiftImageView);

    swiftImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.storyboardWrapperView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
    swiftImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.storyboardWrapperView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
    swiftImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.storyboardWrapperView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true;
    swiftImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.storyboardWrapperView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true;
```

The output I see in Xcode when the layout manager is trying to satisfy conflicting constraints.

```
2017-05-17 22:45:18.351141-0700 My App[29787:7263069] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x170096670 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x101432d20.midX == 540   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174092520 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x101439120]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x10142f4a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174092570 H:[UIView:0x101439120]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x10142f4a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740936a0 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x101432d20]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x101439120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174093790 UIImageView:0x101432d20.trailing == UIView:0x101439120.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009b260 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x10142f4a0.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174093790 UIImageView:0x101432d20.trailing == UIView:0x101439120.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-05-17 22:45:18.360996-0700 My App[29787:7263069] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x174091cb0 _UILayoutGuide:0x10143e8d0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x174092930 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x10143e8d0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x10142f4a0 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x174091da0 _UILayoutGuide:0x10143ddc0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x174091490 _UILayoutGuide:0x10143ddc0.bottom == UIView:0x10142f4a0.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17009cc50 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x101432d20.midY == 877.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174092660 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x10143e8d0]-(0)-[UIView:0x101439120]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740927a0 V:[UIView:0x101439120]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x10143ddc0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174093380 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x101432d20]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x101439120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174093650 UIImageView:0x101432d20.bottom == UIView:0x101439120.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098830 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x10142f4a0.height == 667   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174093650 UIImageView:0x101432d20.bottom == UIView:0x101439120.bottom   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

When I use Xcode to debug the Debug View Hierarchy

The following linked image shows:

1. The constraints on the parent wrapper UIView.
2. The constraints on the UIImageView created via the storyboard.
3. The constraints on the UIImageView created via Swift.

[constraint values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncJYa.png)

Comment: add this line `swiftImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: That did it! Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your console log, these two lines tell you what's happening:

> (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

.

> NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17009cc50 h=--& v=--&
>   UIImageView:0x101432d20.midY == 877.5   (active)

Adding this line to your code will fix things:

```
swiftImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```