# Setting content mode in UIImageView no longer works in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, ios11, contentmode

I have this code in order to put an UIImageView in the center of a navigation controller bar and properly scale the image:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 28));
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit;

    let image = UIImage(named: "image_title.png");
    imageView.image = image;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
}
```

The code works fine in iOS 10, however in iOS 11 the ".scaleAspectFit" property is not considered and the images is not scaled in the UIImageView size.

I tried with some solutions i found:

- Setting the frame of the UIImageView after setting the "contentMode" property
- Setting imageView.setNeedsLayout()
- Setting imageView.setNeedsDisplay()

unfortunately, no one of these solutions works. The "contentMode" property is simply ignored,

Any idea on what the problem could be?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: may this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040208/5580393

Comment: Hi Shebuka, i tried with some proposed solutions i found:
. setting the frame of the image after setting the "contentMode" property
. setting imageView.setNeedsLayout()
. setting imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
no one of these solutions works. The strange thing is that my code works fine in iOS 10...

Comment: Hi Aditya, thank you for your help, unlikely the proposed solution does not work for me :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me such way (using additional UIView)

```
        let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 40))
        let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img-logo"))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.frame = titleView.bounds
        titleView.addSubview(image)
        viewController.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much nerowolfe! Any idea of why embedding the UIImageView in a UIView solves the problem?

Comment: Have no idea. I can only suppose that nav bar now behaves other way then usual UIView

Answer (score 0):

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img-logo"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```