# Image View In CollectionView Cell Not Respecting .scaleAspectFit

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm programmatically adding image view to collection view cells. The problem is that some images aren't obeying the .scaleAspectFit rule on the image view and appear zoomed with gone edges.

Here is my cell class:

```
    class CellVisitorGallery: UICollectionViewCell {

        let imgView: UIImageView = {
            let iv = UIImageView()
            iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            iv.image = UIImage(named: "fath_logo")
            iv.clipsToBounds = true
            return iv
        }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(imgView)
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true

        // Or
        //imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width, height: contentView.frame.height)
        //imgView.center = contentView.center
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I tried both anchor constraints and frame centering, but both ways give the same result.

Comment: see this may be helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039852/uiimageview-scaleaspectfit-and-autolayout-not-working-programmatically-from-swi

Comment: thanks, I have imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false declared